# Как в foreach к каждому блоку добавить свой класс?

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

```html
<div class="xpress-item xpress-two">
           2
</div>
<div class="xpress-item xpress-three">
            3
</div>
<div class="xpress-item xpress-four">
           4
</div>
<div class="xpress-item xpress-five">
           5
</div>
<div class="xpress-item xpress-six">
           6
</div>
```

мне нужно такие блоки вывести через админку wordpress при помощи acf.
Можно по идее через CSS сделать xpress-item:nth-child(1) и т.д.
Но хочется узнать как это можно сделать при помощи php в foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать таким образом c использованием [NumberFormatter](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.numberformatter.php):

```
<?php
$counter = 0;

$number = new NumberFormatter('en', NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);

foreach ( $array as $value ) {
  $counter++;
  ?>
  <div class="xpress-item xpress-<?php echo $number->format( $counter ); ?>">
    <?php echo $counter; ?>
  </div>
  <?php
}
```

Либо еще можете обойтись без `NumberFormatter` и просто создать массив, где пропишите необходимые имена классов и подучите нужное имя по индексу `$numbers[$counter];`.